# Fluid website website design not responsive on mobile phone

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, tumblr

I'm currently tweaking Syndex tumblr theme, here is what i got – http://mbielskyte.tumblr.com. If you will resize your browser window, you will see that everything is more or less fluid (i used vw's for most sizings). But if i open this blog on mobile phone, i see desktop version – http://cl.ly/image/1k3v1M072U0q.

Container is made with %:

> margin:0 auto; width: 90%;

And for images i'm using max-width:, not just width.

Is there any simple solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumblr uses their own mobile version of a site or theme. 
Take a look [here](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#iphone-themes).
You can overwrite this behaviour.
As mentioned in the comments, here is the solution of the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I know that and i turned it off, please see screenshot i uploaded – http://cl.ly/image/1k3v1M072U0q

Comment: hmmm, do you tried something like that: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: It's probably that comment @chrisツ you should add it to your answer.